# How Do I Iterate Through a Table to Call Each Function Stored In It? (Lua)

Tags: function, loops, for-loop, lua

How can I make this code work? It should print "Function a" then "Function b" but it gives me errors. This is practice for some other files where I have a bunch of functions in a module that I want to iterate through in a main file.

```
--stuff for module ----------------------
local funcs = {}

function funcs.a()
    print("Function a")
end

function funcs.b()
    print("Function b")
end

return funcs

-- stuff for main file---------------

for k,v in pairs(funcs) do
    funcs[k]()
end
```

EDIT: I was trying to make this code work in one file as a test. Once that worked, I planned on moving the pieces to two different files.

If I put the following code all in one file, why does it give me the error **'<eof>' expected near 'for'**?

```
local funcs = {}

function funcs.a()
    print("Function a")
end

function funcs.b()
    print("Function b")
end

return funcs

for k,v in pairs(funcs) do
    v()
end
```

Comment: How did you initialize variable `funcs` in the main file?

Comment: It's only one file at the moment. I was planning on separating them into main and module after I figured out how to make it work.

Comment: error '<eof>' expected near 'for' - Is because of ```return funcs``` thats not in a function.- Delete or comment it out. Another thing is that the ```for do end``` is not checking for the type of ```v``` and thats no good style. Make a simple condition for it like: ```if type(v)=='function' then v() end```

Comment: The `returns funcs` should only be there if you actually put the code into a seperate module file. After a `return` statement, nothing is executed in the current scope. And the compiler doesnt expect to see any keyword after a return in the same scope. This is why you get the compiler error `eof expected` (eof = end of file)

Answer (score 2):

Without an error we can't really help that much, but I guess it's a problem related to `func` being a local variable in your module file.

If your module looks like this:
`module.lua`

```lua
local funcs = {}

function funcs.a()
    print("Function a")
end

function funcs.b()
    print("Function b")
end

return funcs
```

And your main looks like this:
`main.lua`

```lua
dofile("module.lua")

for k,v in pairs(funcs) do
    funcs[k]()
end
```

The variable `funcs` in your `main.lua` will be `nil`.
To use the returned value from the module, you have to assign a new variable in your main when loading the module:

`main.lua`

```lua
-- you can name this variable however you like
local funcs = dofile("module.lua")

for k, v in pairs(funcs) do
    -- you can also use the value directly instead of func[k]
    v()
end
```

Comment: I was trying to run the code I posted in the same file. I mentioned the module thing as clarification of my future plans of implementing the code.

Comment: @Tailcoat if it's in the same file currently, the code after `return funcs` will not be executed

Answer (score 1):

`k` is the key, containing the function name, `v` is the value, containing the function code.

Functions are first-class citizens in `Lua`, so you can simply write:

```
for k,v in pairs(funcs) do
  v()
end
```

It will display:

```
Function a
Function b
```